# Android Expandable lIst View Group Expand Listener

Tags: android

I am using a expandable list view in my application with group expand and group collapse listeners.
 But what happens is the right arrow click in the group row works absolutely perfect but when i tap on the row the group does not expand in a single clcik.
I have to tap it multiple times ,only then it expands.
here is the expandable list view group click listener code:

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
              groupName = _groupNameList.get(i);
              _header = _child.get(groupName);

              if (_header.size() == 1 && _header.get(0).getServiceName().equals(groupName)) {
                   expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
                   String id=_header.get(0).getServiceId();
                   Intent intent = new Intent(CategoryDetails1.this, ServiceSelectionOptionsListActivity.class);
                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = CategoryDetails1.this.getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.VERIFICATION, CategoryDetails1.this.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                   editor.putString(AppConstants.SUBSERVICEID, id);
                   editor.commit();
                   startActivity(intent);

               }
               return false;
          }
 });
```

and here is the header row xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGroupName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@color/selecteditem"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"                         have tried this
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/groupindicator"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_plus" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my getgroup view method

```
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_header, null);
        }
        TextView tvGroupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGroupName);
        tvGroupName.setFocusable(false);             //have tried it also
        ImageView ivgroupicon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.groupindicator);
        // ivgroupicon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.servicescollapseicon));
        tvGroupName.setText((String) getGroup(groupPosition));
        int size = _child.get((String) getGroup(groupPosition)).size();
        view.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
        if (size == 1 && _child.get((String) getGroup(groupPosition)).get(0).getServiceName().equals((String) getGroup(groupPosition))) {
            ivgroupicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else
            ivgroupicon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (b) {
            ivgroupicon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.servicesexpandicon));
        } else {
            ivgroupicon.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.servicescollapseicon));
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Now what I want is i want smooth group expand and collapse listener in my activity.I have tried setFocusable to false in both my xml and adapter files but in Vain.
So guys please suggest me something asap.I am stuck in this from a very long time.

Comment: your _child hashmap does contain too many value ??

Comment: no ,it generally contains 4-5 values

Answer (score 0):

Add below property to your

`TextView` and `ImageView`

```
android:focusable="false"
```

And in Root Layout :`RelativeLayout`

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: still does not collapse in a single click

Comment: you can find more answers in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008286/android-expandablelistview-does-not-expand-or-receive-click-events