# Why I am getting "Cannot remove Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager" in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am trying to remove a fragment but very rarely on Crashlytics I am able to see a bug java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot remove Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager.

I have a separate fragment for fetching user's current location. I use below code to open the fragment.

```
private void openLocationFragment() {
    LocationFragment locationFragment = LocationFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, locationFragment, "location_fragment")
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Now In fragment as soon as i get a location update, I call method onLocationFetched using listener attached to the activity.

Inside this method I remove the fragment using below code.

```
@Override
public void onLocationFetched(Location location) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    LocationFragment locationFragment = (LocationFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("location_fragment");
    if (locationFragment != null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .remove(locationFragment) // Here is the exception
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
    if(location == null){
        fetchUserDetails();
    }else
        fetchCity(location);
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Fatal Exception: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot remove Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager.** 

Fragment LocationFragment{32a2ed0 (d41fc341-baf2-4266-948a-866fba7e57b5) id=0x7f09028b location_fragment} is already attached to a FragmentManager.
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.remove(BackStackRecord.java:316)
       at com.avail.easyloans.feature.marketplace.activities.ActivityMarketplace.onFragmentFetched(ActivityMarketplace.java:909)
       at com.avail.easyloans.base.fragments.LocationFragment.sendLocationToClient(LocationFragment.java:192)
       at com.avail.easyloans.base.fragments.LocationFragment.access$000(LocationFragment.java:46)
       at com.avail.easyloans.base.fragments.LocationFragment$4.onSuccess(LocationFragment.java:220)
       at com.avail.easyloans.base.fragments.LocationFragment$4.onSuccess(LocationFragment.java:214)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(zzn.java:4)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
```

What's wrong am I doing here?

Comment: Are you calling `getSupportFragmentManager()` from different Activities?

Comment: yes, but this fragment is not used in any other activity.

Comment: That would explain your error then - each Activity will have its own `FragmentManager` for managing its own fragments

Comment: @PPartisan If this fragment is not used in any other activity, will it still impact `FragmentManager`

Comment: You can check against the resource id value of the container instead of by tag value with `findFragmentById()`. Alternatively, you can launch your other Activity that contains your Location Fragment

Comment: @PPartisan Can you reference this with some code? I am unable to get what you trying to convey.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android expandablelistview does not expand or receive click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008286/android-expandablelistview-does-not-expand-or-receive-click-events)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expect that each `Activity` is responsible for maintaining its own `Fragment`s. This would means that if the Fragment you are trying to access is associated with another `Activity`'s `FragmentManager`, then your app will fail.

I can think of a couple of ways around this, depending on the behaviour you want. If you don't mind having two `LocationFragment`s having their own separate lifecycles in two separate activities, you can access them with `findFragmentById()` on your `FragmentManager`. I.e.:

```
private void openLocationFragment() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final Fragment current = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    if(current == null || !(current instanceof LocationFragment)) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, LocationFragment.newInstance())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

And do the same in your other Activity. Alternatively, you can invoke your other `Activity` that hosts the `LocationFragment` in `onLocationFetched()`